# BeautifulSoup : Extract 'img alt' Text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse `img alt` text.

Below is the HTML code:

```
[<p class="number">
<img alt="1" src="/img/common_new/ball_1.png"/>
<img alt="10" src="/img/common_new/ball_10.png"/>
<img alt="13" src="/img/common_new/ball_13.png"/>
<img alt="26" src="/img/common_new/ball_26.png"/>
<img alt="32" src="/img/common_new/ball_32.png"/>
<img alt="36" src="/img/common_new/ball_36.png"/>
<span class="plus">+</span>
<span class="number_bonus"><img alt="9" src="/img/common_new/ball_9.png"/> 
</span>
</p>]
```

What I want to do is get `img alt` `[1,10, 13,26,32,36,9]`
What shoud I do by using beautifulsoup?

Comment: Have you tried using the [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) method? You can retrieve the value using the [dictionary-style format](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes). Please post your attempt in the OP so we can see the specific problem you have

Answer (score 2):

You need to install bs4 and requests first. Open cmd and write:

```
pip install bs4
pip install requests
```

Then here is your code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get('your website')
source = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml') 

altlinks = []
imgalt_list = [1, 10, 13, 32, 36]

for x in soup.find_all('img', alt= True): #we find all img alt names
    if x['alt'] in imgalt_list: #if alt name matchs with your numbers
        altlinks.append(x.get('src')) #adding into list
print(altlinks)
```

You can ask any part which you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BeautifulSoup`'s [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> html = '''<p class="number">
<img alt="1" src="/img/common_new/ball_1.png"/>
<img alt="10" src="/img/common_new/ball_10.png"/>
<img alt="13" src="/img/common_new/ball_13.png"/>
<img alt="26" src="/img/common_new/ball_26.png"/>
<img alt="32" src="/img/common_new/ball_32.png"/>
<img alt="36" src="/img/common_new/ball_36.png"/>
<span class="plus">+</span>
<span class="number_bonus"><img alt="9" src="/img/common_new/ball_9.png"/> 
</span>
</p>'''

>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> img_alt = []
>>> for img_tag in soup.find_all('img'):
...     img_alt.append(int(img_tag.get('alt')))  # typecasting to integer
>>> print(img_alt)
[1,10, 13,26,32,36,9]  # Output
```